# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' - Dll & remoting

Tags: c#, dll, remoting, filenotfoundexception, .net-remoting

I'm trying to make a game of Nim where the logic takes place on a server and a client presents the game to get better at .NET Remoting.
I have a dll I built from this class library:

```
namespace Nim_Common
{
    public interface computerCommon
    {
        int[] startGame(int columnNumber);
        int[] computeTurn(int[] penStatus); 
        bool checkWin();
    }
}
```

That dll I add as a reference to my client project and my server project, and add the dll to the bin/Debug directory in each project.

This is the relevant part of my client code:

```
using Nim_Common;

namespace Nim
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            private computerCommon computerServerHandler;
            ...
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            computerToolStripMenuItem.Select();
            newColumnNumber = -1; 
            RemotingConfiguration.Configure("client.exe.config");
            computerServerHandler = (computerCommon)Activator.GetObject(typeof(computerCommon), "http://localhost:1234/_Server_");
            StartGame(this, null);
        }
private void StartGame(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int max = 0;
            if(columns != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++) Controls.Remove(columns[i]);
            int[] temp = computerServerHandler.startGame(newColumnNumber);
            columns = new Column[temp.Length];
            ...
        }
```

And in the server part:

```
using Nim_Common;

namespace Nim_Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemotingConfiguration.Configure("server.exe.config");
        }
    }

    class ServerPart : MarshalByRefObject, computerCommon
    {
        ...

        public ServerPart()
        {
            ...
        }
        public int[] startGame(int columnNumber)
        {
            ...
        }
        public int[] computeTurn(int[] penStatus)
        {
            ...
        }

        public bool checkWin()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

server.exe.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <channels>
        <channel ref="http server" port="1234" />
      </channels>
      <service>
        <wellknown mode ="SingleCall" type="Nim_Server.ServerPart, Nim_Server" objectUri="_Server_" />
      </service>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

client.exe.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <channels>
        <channel ref="http client" />
      </channels>

      <client>
        <wellknown type="Nim_Common.computerCommon, Nim_Common" url="http://localhost:1234" />
      </client>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

My firewall is off if that matters.
Everything is fine in compile time, the server runs fine. When the client reaches this line, it throws the exception:

```
int[] temp = computerServerHandler.startGame(newColumnNumber);
```

The exception is something like:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or one of its dependencies, the system could not find "Nim_Common". // This is shown in my native language so I'm improvising a bit with the translation.
```

What is going on and how do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error from one of my own compiled dlls. It turns out I had filled in the  AssemblyCultureAttribute in my AssemblyInfo.cs file. The project built without issue but would not load in any referenced projects when used.

According to msdn :

> Putting this attribute on an assembly and using something other than the empty string ("") for the culture name will make this assembly look like a satellite assembly, rather than a main assembly that contains executable code. Labeling a traditional code library with this attribute will break it, because no other code will be able to find the library's entry points at runtime.